# vector space $V$ over infinite field implies infinitely many $W^\prime$ satisfying $W\oplus W^\prime=V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that for a vector space $V$ over an infinite field and a proper subspace $W$, there are infinitely many $W^\prime$ satisfying $W\oplus W^\prime=V$.

I have no idea what to do... Help!

Comment: What's the "worst possible" $W$ ? Also, have you looked at the simpler case $V=\mathbb{R^2}$?

Comment: @Hmm. Not sure what you mean by worst possible. About $\mathbb R^2$ - sure: elements are independent if they're not proportional. I just don't see what to make of the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a basis $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ of $W$ complete it in a basis $((v_i)_{i\in I},(w_j)_{j\in J})$ of $V$, then the subspace generated by $(w_j)$ is supplementary to $W$, let $v_{i_0},i_0\in I$, for every $k\in K$, ($K$ is the infinite field) consider the space $W_k$, generated $(w_j+kv_{i_0})_{j\in J}$. Show that $W_k$ is supplementary to $W$ and $W_k$  is distinct of $W_{k'}$ if $k\neq k'$.